# RabbitMQ - XML string to C# Object

Tags: c#, string, xml-parsing, rabbitmq, .net-6.0

I am connecting to a RabbitMQ queue. Various messages are sent down this queue as XML strings. Each message could be one of many predefined types. What is the best way to convert from this XML string to a C# object when I do not know what th

Comment: What in your google search proved insufficient?  There are several built-in xml parsing libraries, including `System.Xml.Linq` and `System.Xml`.

Comment: My biggest problem is working out what object I need to map from the string. Unless I use string.Contains("tag") in a if, ifelse, else block